# Excluding a custom taxonomy term breaks wp_get_post_terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I'm trying to exclude one custom taxonomy from an archive page, and then show the terms of the returned posts.

When I run WP_Query to exclude the custom term, it returns the posts correctly, but no longer fetches the terms array when using `wp_get_post_terms()`. I suspect that not querying in the positive prevents it from fetching the terms. Here's what my code looks like:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
        array( 'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'documenttype',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array('pressreleases'),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                ),

            ) ) 
        );
//then later, in the loop ...
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($query->post->ID,'documenttype');
// var_dump($terms) shows an empty array
```

Comment: The terms array is not empty if I remove the 'operator' key from the query.

Comment: maybe obvious, but do the posts have other terms in that taxonomy associated with them?

Comment: Yep. The other terms show up when I run a query that doesn't exclude a term.

Comment: any plugins or filters in the theme that may be modifying the results? your query works as expected with `wp_get_post_terms` in Twenty Eleven and the Codex code for adding a taxonomy. try to eliminate any other factors.

Comment: Hm. In the Twenty Eleven theme with a fresh install, I get even stranger results. Querying in the negative `('NOT IN')` brings no results at all, when querying in the positive brings in posts in the terms requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help everybody.

I was using a custom post type and forgot to include

```
'post_type'=>'my_custom_post_type'
```

I finally got to the problem by doing a `var_dump` on the `WP_Query` object and looking at the SQL. Running the query directly on the database and picking through it, I eventually found my error.